# Jquery droppable: drop item based on a condition otherwise bounce back

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I have some boxes and some texts. I'm dragging the texts to that boxes. 
The html for the texts which should be dragged is:

```
<div class="module-drag-text ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">text1</div>
<div class="module-drag-text ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">text2</div>
<div class="module-drag-text ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">text3</div>
```

and the html of the boxes in which I'm dragging that text is:

```
<div class="module-drag-box ui-droppable"></div>
<div class="module-drag-box ui-droppable"></div>
<div class="module-drag-box ui-droppable"></div>
```

So the whole html looks like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="module-drag-text ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">text1</div>
    <div class="module-drag-text ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">text2</div>
    <div class="module-drag-text ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">text3</div>
    <div class="module-drag-box ui-droppable"></div>
    <div class="module-drag-box ui-droppable"></div>
    <div class="module-drag-box ui-droppable"></div>
</div>
```

Now what I want is the `text1` should be only drop to the first `droppable` div and `text2` is to second `droppable` div.

If a user tries to drag `text1` into second `droppable` div, it should be bounce back to its original position.

The code I have written for drag and drop is:

```
drag : function() {
    dragText.draggable({
      containment : ".popup",
      revert : "invalid"
    });
    dragBox.droppable({
      drop : function(event, ui) {
        var drop = jQuery(event.target);
        drop.html(ui.draggable.html());
        ui.draggable.remove();
        drop.droppable("destroy");
      }
    });
  },
```

But I don't where should I write the logic for it. I know it has the `accept` attribute but didn't know how to use it based on my problem.

Comment: is it possible to add a fiddle ?

Comment: I don't know about this

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `accept` option

> **accept** option determine which element (or group of elements) is
>   accepted by the target droppable.

Use `revert` option to bring back the draggable to original place

```
$("#draggable, #draggable-nonvalid").draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });

$("#droppable").droppable({
    accept: '#draggable-nonvalid',

});
```

See the below demo where I have done it for text 1 to drop in a droppable , rest of the text wont drop in that droppable. Similarly you can do for  rest

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/amarsingh/tM7cp/381/)

[**Working Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/amarsingh/tM7cp/383/) -  For dynamic accept selection

```
$(".dragg").draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });

$("#droppable").droppable({
    accept: function(d){if($(this).hasClass(d.attr("id"))){return true;}},

});
```

Comment: I will write the droppable function for each box in this case. it should be dynamic.

Comment: but anyways there needs to be some connection between draggable and droppable to achieve your requirement. You can make a logic for that using `class` and `ID` of draggables/droppables.

Comment: @Ahmad : checkout my second demo . You only need to put the id of draggable into the class of droppable ,,, Rest is handled